# In what regional variations of English is "Do things like <plain-form-verb>" acceptable?

Tags: grammar, dialects

Just googling "do things like" or "does things like" will reveal quite a number of hits, some even from textbooks and the like suggesting that many English speakers think nothing of following it with a plain-form verb, and one of the first hits is
https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/do-things-like-do-sth.3564075/

which claims it's perfectly normal to form sentences like this. But to my ears it simply sounds wrong, and I know I'm not the only one.
The original sentence that triggered this curiosity was "On weekends I do things like go shopping and watch TV", which to me isn't something I could easily imagine a native speaker saying, but at least a few apparently native speakers thought it was fine!
Interestingly, one of the early google hits is "They feel pleased and proud when they get to do things like drive a car for the first time", and while my instinct is to want to correct it to "driving a car", it doesn't sound quite as blatantly wrong as the previous example, for no logical reason that I can surmise.
Given it's not grammatically incorrect to say "I do drive a car", I suppose in principle "I do things like drive a car" might work, if "things like" is some sort of adverbial modifier rather part of the noun phrase "things like {noun-phrase}", but I'm not convinced that's the explanation for this usage.

(Edit: for those who think it sounds OK, would you be OK with "Things like go shopping and watch TV I do on weekends"?)

Comment: American English, in particular, is extremely lax with "the rules". I was astounded when I went to work for a large corporation (at the age of 45) and realized that most of the younger "big heads" could not even write a memo with grammatically correct sentences. In anything other than legal or formal publications, editing is non-existent. Proper use of the language is no longer a method of identifying the college educated. (Now all we can do is look at their pay stubs.)

Comment: This is unfortunately widely the case, and is exceedingly sad. I would add, however, that I worked in Europe for many, many years, and the problem exists in the UK as well.

Answer (score -1):

> "On weekends I do things like go shopping and watch TV",

I assume you would have no difficulty with

"For lunch I eat something healthy, like an apple, a salad or sardines." (Note the comma, which as been erroneously omitted in your example.)

You will note that the words after "like" (=such as; for example) form a list of examples.

**go shopping** and **watch TV** are reduced clauses: the subject has been omitted.

(We can see this more clearly in "On weekends ***he does*** things like ***goes*** shopping and ***watches*** TV.")

Thus, in full, the example sentence is

*"On weekends I do things **for example/such as, I** go shopping and **I** watch TV"*,

Comment: Not quite sure what your point is - "On weekends he does things like goes shopping and watches TV" barely sounds like English at all!

But yes, "eat something...like an apple" is fine, as 'apple' is a noun.  But I wouldn't say "I do something healthy, like walk".

Comment: @DylanNicholson There we have the difference in personal use: I would. "Cambridge English Empower Pre-intermediate Student's Book" By Adrian Doff, (et al) Page 170 "*Friends tell me I should do something relaxing after work, like go for a walk on the beach.*":)

Comment: And that's written as an example as a normal grammatical sentence? Wow.  Just sounds flat out wrong to me, I would be floored to hear a native speaker say it.  Especially in that sentence where you already have the gerund form "relaxing".  In fact I would almost wonder why you bother using it there and not just say "I should do something relax after work"!

Comment: @DylanNicholson "So, Do You Like ... Stuff?: A Collection of Things" - Mike Kenny - 2011 "*My major in college was History, and I have used that extensive knowledge of historical events to do things like watch reality television and create a blog.*" ++ Hi, My Name Is John: My Story of Survival with Autism and ... - Page 56 by
John Malatesta - 2012 "*.. and I knew what they told me at that time that high school students were allowed to do things like eat food at school.*" There are plenty more examples out there. I'm surprised you haven't come across any.

Comment: On the rare occasions I come across a written sentence like that I assume it's just a mistake!  Grammatical errors in writing are a bit different from those in speech.

Comment: @DylanNicholson "Cambridge English Empower Pre-intermediate Student's Book" By Adrian Doff, (et al) is unlikely to use errors - I think you will have to accept the the construction is simply new to your idiolect.

Comment: I don't have any trouble accepting that it's used, but am I curious about how widely and by what sort of speakers. To me it sounds as wrong as regionalisms such as "The grass needs mowed" (and yep, that's grammatical to some speakers).

Comment: @DylanNicholson *"I don't have any trouble accepting that it's used,"* The guidance on good grammar states "When enough people are wrong, they are right." This explains why we are not speaking Old English. My perception is that the form in question is fine: yours is contrary. I  note that I speak British English, and you speak American English. However, even in American English, as per my examples, (*high school students were allowed to do things like eat food at school.*) the form is used.

Comment: Nope, I'm Australian. I don't think I've heard it that form used here.

Comment: @DylanNicholson: Apologies for the national mistake - I associate "flat out wrong" with AE (but can now hear it in AusE). ++ Let me point you to an Australian government website: "https://www.healthdirect.gov.au/nervous-system *"The nervous system is made up of the brain, spinal cord and nerves. It is the body’s communication system that controls much of what your body does. It allows you **to do things like walk, speak, swallow, breathe and learn**, and controls how your body reacts in an emergency.*"

Comment: Nice find.  And to be honest for whatever reason I can't explain that sentence doesn't grate nearly as much as many of the others, though I'd still prefer "things like walking, speaking etc.".  But you surely can't say "Things like walk, speak, swallow, breathe and learn are what the nervous system allows you to do".

Comment: @DylanNicholson In "do something relaxing after work", "relaxing" isn't a gerund; it's a participle modifying "something".

Comment: True! But I can't think of too many cases where using the either the plain or the -ing form is possible.

Comment: @DylanNicholson *you surely can't say "Things like walk, speak, swallow, breathe and learn are what the nervous system allows you to do"* Change "like" for "for example", and you will see that you can. Essentially "like" and "for example" are the same thing.

Comment: Huh? "Things for example walk, speak...are what the nervous system allows" is definitely not a valid sentence for me! But I'd never say "Things, for example walking, speaking,... are what the nervous system allows" either. "Things, for example" is not a substitute for "Things like" in this case. You could potentially use "Bodily functions" in both cases though.

Comment: It seems that I cannot do things like lead a horse to water... We will have to agree to disagree.

Answer (score -1):

> On weekends I do things like go shopping and watch TV

Strict prescriptive grammarians would count this as an error. I personally would say "On weekends I do things like *going* shopping and *watching* TV"

Because *going* and *watching* are gerunds, they can take the place of nouns, and are therefore "things".

The version you speak of replaces the gerund with the bare infinitive (i.e. the infinitive without "to").

In full the original sentence would read, "On weekends I do things like *to go shopping* and *to watch* TV", and that sounds clumsy to me.

Comment: I certainly don't count myself as a strict prescriptivist, though until recently I did think it would be safe to say "I do things like go shopping" was an ungrammatical sentence in standard English.

Comment: 'I like / enjoy / take part in things like ...' certainly don't take a bare infinitive.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth  That's why I said strict grammarians would count it an error. You clearly do and that is fine by me. However it is in common usage - at least where I live (SE England)

Comment: You're misrepresenting me. Saying 'A', A'' and A''' are wrong' is not the same as saying 'A is wrong'. I can't find an authority licensing (or forbidding) "He loves to do things like go fishing with his dad" and hence I wouldn't presume to write an 'answer'. I can't be sure, but perhaps someone thinks your lack of supporting evidence for your 'Strict ...' claim warrants the downvote.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> On weekends I do things like go shopping and watch TV.
> ```

I agree with you, and I would say "On weekends I do things like going shopping and watching TV." Other variations jar on me a little.

That said I have often heard statements like your example, and they are perfectly understandable. In Australia they are more associated with a "broad" Australian accent. I think they are less markers of regional differences and more markers of cultural or educational differences. I suspect that in time they will be acceptable even in formal English.